# Symfony 6.2 Routing - Check if a parameter matches a row in database

Tags: php, database, symfony, routes

In symfony 6.2 how can I do so a method is called to check if the first parameter matches something in database?

I tried setting up a service to setup a Custom Route Loader, but I'm not managing to add all the routes, it only adds the last one.

This is my service:

```
<?php

namespace App\Service;

use App\Entity\Country;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Loader;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\RouteLoaderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;

class RouteHandler implements RouteLoaderInterface
{

    private $managerRegistry;

    private $router;

    private $isLoaded = false;

    public function __construct(RouterInterface $router, ManagerRegistry $managerRegistry)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->managerRegistry = $managerRegistry;
    }

    public function __invoke(): RouteCollection
    {
        if (true === $this->isLoaded) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Do not add the routes twice');
        }

        $countries = $this->managerRegistry->getRepository(Country::class)->findAll();

        $routes = new RouteCollection();
        foreach ($countries as $country) {
            $name = strtolower($country->getName());
            $acronym = strtolower($country->getAcronym());
            $path = "/{$acronym}";
            $defaults = [
                '_controller' => 'App\Controller\Country::index',
            ];

            $route = new Route($path, $defaults, []);
            $routeName = "app_country";
            $routes->add($routeName, $route);
        }

        $this->isLoaded = true;

        return $routes;
    }
}
```

My current routes.yaml:

```
controllers:
    resource:
        path: ../src/Controller/
        namespace: App\Controller
    type: attribute

country_routes:
    resource: 'App\Service\RouteHandler'
    type: service
```

My services.yaml:

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
    App\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'

    App\Service\RouteHandler:
        class: App\Service\RouteHandler
        arguments: [ '@router.default','@doctrine' ]
```

```
bin/console debug:router
```

returns only one instance of app_country and I want one for each country, how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it seemed I needed to use `$routes->addCollection($routes)` and change the route name to contain the specified row